# Autodesk ForgeViewer: Snapper Function Fails with Overlaid Models Depending on Load Order

Tags: javascript, typescript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-bim360

I am facing an issue with the Autodesk Forge Viewer's v7.87 snapper functionality when dealing with two overlaid models on top of eachother.

- The snapper works as expected when I follow a specific sequence: first loading Model id: 1, then Model id: 2. In this scenario, the snapper interacts correctly with both models.
- Conversely, if I reverse the loading order, starting with Model id: 2 and subsequently loading Model id: 1, the snapper fails to function. It seems to be unable to recognize Model id: 2 at all and every hitTest returns Model id: 2 no matter what I hover or click.

[image: example]

**Scenario 1 (Working)**:

When I load Model id: 1 first and then Model id: 2, the snapper functions correctly.

[image: snap]

**Scenario 2 (Not Working):**

However, if I load Model id: 2 first and then Model id: 1, the snapper does not work.

[image: no snap]

Is there a workaround or a solution to ensure the snapper works regardless of the model loading order? Any insights or suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried this: https://aps.autodesk.com/cloud_and_mobile/2016/02/changing-gethitpoint-to-return-dbid.html

Comment: @varunpatil This didn't work but the function idAtPixel does return me the correct dbid no matter which loading order. Is there a way to use that to do snapping or get the faces?

Comment: yes, if you have dbid, viewer.select(dbid) you can do a selection. Also get the fragmentsvar dbid = objectIds[i];

        //from dbid to node, to fragid
        var it = viewer.model.getData().instanceTree;

        it.enumNodeFragments(dbid, function (fragId) {console.log(fragid)},false)

Comment: The snapper manager code, defaults to using the first model loaded.  Do you have the ability to know the  load order up front?  You can control the multi-model load order.     The only other workaround involves modifying the snapper extension hit-test to handle multi-model loading.

Comment: @varunpatil I'm not looking to do a selection but find the face the mouse is hovering, the method you suggested gives me the same fragId no matter where I hover, but even if it was working properly, I'm not sure how from the fragId I can find the correct face the mouse is hovering.

Comment: @michaelbeale I'm able to know the load order, but it might change all the time and I won't know which model is the one making it fail. I am probably however able to change the snapper extension hitTest, how would you go about making it handle multi model loading?

Comment: Could you please provide more details on how to reproduce this issue? Is it happening with arbitrary two models, or is the model that is breaking the snapper somehow "different"?

Comment: @PetrBroz nothing special about that model, it is indeed arbitrary. However it does only happen when the models are overlaid on top of each other. In that particular scenario, 1st model is the building and the 2nd is its skeleton. I'm also viewing it into through a section view, so that's a vertical slice in the middle of the building. I can edit the post and add some more gifs of me doing the slicing if that helps.